Why is my computer omitting a result which online compilers aren't? Also, it is taking 35 seconds to run
In terminal -
PS C:\Users\Paradox\Documents\Prog\C> cd "c:\Users\Paradox\Documents\Prog\C\" ; if ($?) { gcc armstrong.c -o armstrong } ; if ($?) { .\armstrong }
Enter the upper limit for the list of Armstrong Numbers : 

Output for 1000 as input:
All-Armstrong number between 1 and 1000 are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 370 371 407

It's omitting 153.
Also, it's taking 35 seconds to print the first statement. Apart from that, it prints final output instantaneously. I am using mingw btw.
I don't think it should take this long just to print first statement.
adding round(pow(r,i)) fixes the ommition but it is still taking too long to compute.
Code -
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int n1, a, n2, i, r;
    printf("Enter the upper limit for the list of Armstrong Numbers : ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("All-Armstrong number between 1 and %d are: ", n1);
    for (int k = 1; k <= n1; k++)
    {
        a = 0,n2 = k,i=0;
        
        do
        {
            n2/= 10;
            i++;
        } 
        while (n2!= 0);
       
        n2 = k;

        do
        {
            r = n2 % 10;
            a+=pow(r, i);
            n2/= 10;
        } 
        while (n2!= 0);

        if (a == k)
        {
            printf("%d ", a);
        }
    }
}



I am getting very skeptical about the correctness of the code once I see pow() in integer calculations.

yeah, it's probably returning something very slightly less than expected (like 2.999999999999995 instead of 3), so you end up adding one less than desired.

What do you get if you replace a+=pow(r, i); with double p = pow(r, i); printf("%.20g\n", p); a += p;

Use ipow() instead of pow(): int ipow(int b, unsigned e) { int res = 1; while (e--) res *= b; return res; } Beware overflows, you may want to use long if dealing with larger values.

ipow() doesn't work?

ipow() working on ideone: https://ideone.com/tWSnPv

So, yes, pow seems to give incorrect result. a+=pow(r, i); with double p = pow(r, i); printf("%.20g\n", p); a += p; gives a very long incorrect resultl.

I hadn't learned functions yet so I had trouble understanding ipow function. I still don't get the while condition but I think I'll be able to figure it out. Could you please tell me why ipow works and pow doesn't?

Okay, I got it (understood the function) but still don't know why ipow works but pow doesn't. Also, why are we using int for b and unsigned for e here ? [What "unsigned e" means here? Ik e gets the value of e in pow(b,e) but I was under the impression we have to use a data type along with unsigned, like unsigned int. So which datatype gets assigned when we don't explicitly enter any? ]. Also, I found that using double res gives correct result while just int omits any no. longer than 7.  Why is long preferred over double here?
